# Testing the values of Views fields

Tags: views, theming

I have a View that displays four types of field (`field_ba_before`, `field_photo_gallery`, `field_body_image`, `field_image_position`).

In my `views-view-fields.tpl.php` file, I have created a variable called `$class`. I want the variable of `$class` to change according to the values of the four fields.

Not every Views row result will use all of the fields, so in my code, I have used IF statements to check if the field exists.

This is my code:

```
<?php if(($fields['field_ba_before']-> content || $fields['field_photo_gallery']-> content)): ?>
<?php $class = "content-aside-layered"; ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php if (($fields['field_body_image']-> content)): ?>

    <?php if (($fields['field_image_position']-> content) == 'image_position_right'): ?>
    <?php $class = "content-aside"; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if (($fields['field_image_position']-> content) == 'image_position_left'): ?>
    <?php $class = "aside-content"; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if (($fields['field_image_position']-> content) == 'image_position_bottom'): ?>
    <?php $class = "content-aside-layered"; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if (($fields['field_image_position']-> content) == 'image_position_default'): ?>
    <?php $class = theme_get_setting('body_image_position'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>


<div class="<?php print $class; ?>"> </div>
```

I am not sure why it is not working. Is there a special way of testing the values of Views fields? Thanks for any help that can be offered!

Comment: Dont use too common views template: views-view-fields.tpl.php - instead of this click on Information in Views editing, there's try select last style (rows, or field), and access fields values from $rows variable. For investigating this structure, use Devel module and use next code: dsm();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views provide to the template the html output of the field and not the actual value or a means to detect if it is empty or not. You will thus need to compare the field->content value with the expected html output. Assuming that you use Drupal 7 and you haven't overriden the field output or you haven't set the field as hidden ("exclude from display" option), the default field output is:

```
opendiv class="field-content"> ... html output here ... closediv>
```

Steps to achieve what you're trying to:

1) Add a function like the following: (replace "opendiv" and "closediv" with html open and close div tags, I couldn't get the editor not to filter them)

```
function mymodule_views_field_compare_value($field, $expected_value) {
      if ($field->content == 'opendiv class="field-content">'.$extected_value.'closediv>') {
          return true;
      }
      return false;
  }
```

2) To check if a field is not empty do:

```
if (!mymodule_views_field_compare_value($fields['field_ba_before'], '')) {
}
```

3) To check the value of the image positioning:

```
if (mymodule_views_field_compare_value($fields['field_image_position'], 'image_position_default')) {
}
```

This should help. You can use dpm($fields['field_image_position']) (if you're using the devel module) or var_dump($fields['field_image_position']) to check the actual output of the field, in case it is different than just 'image_position_default', I don't know what type of field it is.